# Sierra Mail Plugin

Tags: cocoa, macos-sierra

A client of mine who has a Mail plugin ("unofficial" of course since Apple does not provide support for mail plugin) wants me to update its pluginto Sierra.

When I look at the code swizzled, I see that one of the main classes he used is the SignatureBundle, which inherits from MVMailBundle. In this class, we can find many signature related functions like addSIgnature, signatureWithId and accountsEmails.

My problem is that this class no longer exists on Sierra, and I can't find any other class that I can use. 
Do you have any clue that would help me figure out who to update his plugin? I know it is not official SDK, but who knows, maybe one of you already tried to update a mail plugin

Thanks for your help

Comment: No, anyone? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you rightly say, the SignatureBundle class is no longer present inside Mail's main executable.  Such is life when you are using undocumented classes. :-)

Best advice I can give you is to take a look at the Mail-related frameworks inside /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks.  If you are lucky, Apple may have simply moved this class into one of the private frameworks.  However, if you are using NSClassFromString to find the class and getting nil back, then you're probably out of luck.

In which case, it's a long, tedious trawl around in the innards looking for the exact functionality you want.  Your best bet in this case is Mail.framework itself.  It contains a couple of hopeful-looking classes called MFSignature and MFSignatureManager.  Some disassembly required...

Comment: Thanks for your answer though it came a little late. A friend pointed out MFSignatureManager and MFSignature, and hopefully it did the trick :-). Thanks a lot for your answer though, I'll use it as the rightful answer ^^